# Object and Image Distance from Image height, Object height, and focal length

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics

Is there a way to find the object and image distances from the object height, image height, and focal length? I understand that the magnification is equal to  $-\frac{d_i}{d_o}$ or $\frac{h_i}{h_o}$, but how does that relate to the mirror equation, $\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{d_i} + \frac{1}{d_o}$?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty trivial problem to me :p. Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with,

\begin{align*}
    & f \text{ represents the Focal Length of the mirror.} \\
    & v \text{ represents the Image Distance, which is the distance from the mirror to the image.} \\
    & u \text{ represents the Object Distance, which is the distance from the mirror to the object.} \\
    & h_i \text{ represents the Image Height.} \\
    & h_o \text{ represents the Object Height.}
\end{align*}

As per your question, we are provided with the values of the Object Height, Image Height, and the Focal Length of the mirror.

For simplicity's sake, suppose,
\begin{align}
\text{Image Height } (h_{i}) = 10cm \\
\text{Object Height } (h_{o}) = 5cm \\
\text{Focal Length } (f) = 10cm
\end{align}

Then by the magnification formula,

\begin{align}
&\text{Magnification } (M) = \frac{h_{i}}{h_{o}} = -\frac{v}{u} \\
&\implies \frac{h_{i}}{h_{o}} = -\frac{v}{u} \\
&\implies \frac{10cm}{5cm} = -\frac{v}{u} \\
&\implies 2 = -\frac{v}{u} \\
&\implies 2u = -v \\
&\implies v = -2u \quad \text{... (i)}
\end{align}

Now by the mirror formula,
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{v} + \frac{1}{u} \\
&\implies \frac{1}{10} = \frac{1}{-2u} + \frac{1}{u} \quad \text{(v = -2u, from (i))} \\
&\implies \frac{1}{10} = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{2u} \\
&\implies \frac{1}{10} = \frac{2 - 1}{2u} \\
&\implies \frac{1}{10} = \frac{1}{2u} \\
&\implies u = 5 \\
&∴ u = 5cm \\
&\implies v = -2u = -2 \times (5 cm) = -10 cm
\end{align}

I hope you now understand how this works in a more general sense.